# Python Programming String Handling Functions

Tags: python

So, I'm a beginner to programming. I am trying to create a program where the user can input a sentence and the program will tell the user how many letters are in that sentence.

```
counter=0

wrd=raw_input("Please enter a short sentence.")

if wrd.isalpha():
counter=counter+1
print "You have" + str(counter) +"in your sentence."
```

When I enter this, my output is blank. What is my mistake in this program?

Comment: You haven't indented `counter=counter+1` I think. Besides this, you aren't exactly using a loop

Comment: Can you use `len()`? That's the easiest and fastest way to do what you describe. Of course you'd still need to filter out the all the non-letters from your sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all as @kalpesh mentioned, the statement `counter=counter+1` should be indented.

Second of all, you need to iterate over the entire string entered and then count the number of characters or whatever the logic you need.

```
counter=0

wrd=raw_input("Please enter a short sentence.")

for i in wrd:
    if i.isalpha():
        counter = counter+1

print "You have " + str(counter) +"in your sentence."
```

Once you start learning more, then you can use the below code,

```
counter=[]
count = 0
wrd=raw_input("Please enter a short sentence.")

counter = [len(i) for i in wrd.split() if i.isalpha()]

print "You have " + str(sum(counter)) +"in your sentence."
```

I am just splitting the word and then checking if it is alpha or not and using the list comprehension to iterate over the string entered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent code inside `if` blocks. In the code you have provided, you've forgotten to indent `counter = counter + 1`.

You are missing a loop across all characters of `wrd`. Try this instead,

```
counter = 0
wrd = raw_input("Please enter a short sentence.")
# Iterate over every character in string
for letter in wrd:
  # Check if the letter is an alphabet
  if letter.isalpha():
    # Increment counter only in this condition
    counter += 1

print "You have " + str(counter) + " in your sentence."
```

Answer (score 0):

wrd.isalpha() returns a boolean (true or false). So if the function returns true, counter=counter+1 will be called once (and only once). You need to iterate through every letter of wrd and call isalpha() on each letter.

Answer (score 0):

You could always remove the spaces from your sentence using replace() then use len() to get how many characters are in the sentence.

For example:

```
sentence = input("Type in a sentence: ") # Ask the user to input a sentence
sentence = sentence.replace(" ", "") # Replace the spaces in the sentence with nothing
print("Your sentence is " + str(len(sentence)) +  " characters long") # Use len() to print out number of letters in the sentence
```